# Potential problems sending text over ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am building a web app in asp c#. When I am saving data in a form, I dont want to do a post back to save it, I want to save it through Ajax. I am just wondering would there be any potential problems the system will encounter sending text through ajax.

The max length of text being sent will be around 500 chars.

Comment: No. why'd you think there would be problems with sending text ajax? Oh and you should try to improve your accept-rate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was just thinking if that there might be a problem with special characters or some other dangers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you may have is if the text contains characters that can break the post line.
So you need to encode them using the `encodeURIComponent(TextToBeSend)`

More about encoding: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, asynchronous Javascript calls to server is reliable enough for data transmission. You can count on AJAX on even much more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Keep in mind, you may need to escape some characters.  Sending text with single and/or double quotes can get messy.  Also, if you are using .NET 4 (or 3.5 I believe) you can take advantage of the `ClientIDMode="static"` attribute to avoid using `<%=myControl.ClientID%>` in referencing ASP.NET controls in Javascript.